# Where and how does Cassandra store and update per-cell timestamp?

Tags: cassandra

I'm currently working on implementing a storage algorithm idea on Cassandra,
and for this idea to work,
I need to store some per-cell metadata in addition to the per-cell timestamp.

my question is,
where in the code base does Cassandra handle this per-cell timestamp?
I've skimmed through the write path and can't seem to find it.

Comment: Did you look in https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/rows/NativeCell.java?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to start here:

Cell.java:

```
  32 /**
  33  * A cell is our atomic unit for a single value of a single column.
  34  * <p>
  35  * A cell always holds at least a timestamp that gives us how the cell reconcile. We then
  36  * have 3 main types of cells:
  37  *   1) live regular cells: those will also have a value and, if for a complex column, a path.
  38  *   2) expiring cells: on top of regular cells, those have a ttl and a local deletion time (when they are expired).
  39  *   3) tombstone cells: those won't have value, but they have a local deletion time (when the tombstone was created).
  40  */
```

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob;f=src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/rows/Cell.java;h=300bbce12a225fc7630daee78d2fe64b6a868c73;hb=3b56d4df40800f76dcf2c0019af43b7dbc244c57

AbstractCell.java (inherits Cell.java):

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob;f=src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/rows/AbstractCell.java;h=bfe7396c23c45a3ed8da479551c8e1a6fa23f76b;hb=3b56d4df40800f76dcf2c0019af43b7dbc244c57

and here

NativeCell.java (inherits AbstractCell.java):

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob;f=src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/rows/NativeCell.java;h=c4cb6c1342cba700f5b059d1f5a9108bb83b2a66;hb=3b56d4df40800f76dcf2c0019af43b7dbc244c57

But if you want to use Cassandra for your storage solution, store the timestamp and your metadata explicitly and don't use cell metadata from cassandras internals.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for, however, you said that you don't recommend that I modify Cassandra internal to storage my per-cell metadata, can you please elaborate?

Comment: If I got it right you want to build a customized version of Cassandra. You will need to maintain it yourself and keep up with upstream development and reapply your patches. Also you need to patch the drivers you use to get access to this metadata. It might a) that Cassandra is the wrong tool or b) just storing the timestamp and your metadata as separate fields along with your data and have full control.

Comment: This timestamp inside the cell is intended for Cassandras internal use - even if it can be accessed from the drivers. If you want a timestamp and metadata under your control just insert them into a (separate if search / fast access is needed) table. Sort of INSERT INTO foobar (id, timestamp, metadata) VALUES ( ... ). If needed Cassandra has list and map types you could use for metadata.

Comment: Thank you Mandraenke again for your helpful answer and comments!